# Having problems with CSS cross browser look and feel

Tags: css

I'm having some problems getting this to look good in IE, FireFox, Opera, Chrome and Safari.

Opera and Firefox are the same, but IE, Chrome and Safari has a bit different look.
Especially the input rounded corners in Chrome.

This is my code http://jsfiddle.net/VKuD6/2/

Can anyone point me into the right direction of getting "identical" cross browser look and feel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search boxes in webkit have some default styles you'll want to get rid of using this:

```
-webkit-appearance: textfield;
```

Should sort it, at least partly. <strike>You do loose the clear text cross button though.</strike> - Apparently not

Also, you should check this out, good information about the search input http://css-tricks.com/webkit-html5-search-inputs/

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Do you know how I can get the same height in Chrome/Safari as I have in Firefox/Opera?

Comment: Ok, that cleared up a few things. To bad Web kits has so many restrictions on the search field :(

Comment: If you set the font-size, line-height, padding, border and margin that should help. Those are all things that affect the size of an input. If you do that they should be pretty much identical I'd think. You may be able to use something like this: http://bastianallgeier.com/css_browser_selector/ to target specific browsers to iron out all the little niggles.